# can't render <br> while setting text in <p>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why HTML can't render line breaks if the text of `<p>` was set via javascript?

see sample here: [WHY?](http://jsfiddle.net/FyVzF/107/)

Below are the codes:

```
<p id="par"></p>
<br>

<p>IT WORKS<br />wire.<br>pin..</p>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#par").text('I\n CANT<br />INSERT<br>LINE BREAKS!'+'<br />'+'FFFF;br/KKK');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set **HTML** you have to use [**`.html()`**](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2).

From the [**`.text()`**](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) documentation (emphasis mine):

> We need to be aware that this method **escapes the string provided as necessary** so that it will render correctly in HTML.

Answer (score 3):

use `.html()` instead of using `.text()`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FyVzF/109/)

Answer (score 3):

Because of if you want to set HTML inside `<p>` or any DOM element instead of normal text.

## Use [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$("#par").html('I\n CANT<br />INSERT<br>LINE BREAKS!'+'<br />'+'FFFF;br/KKK');
```

[**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FyVzF/110/)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use **.html()** instead of **.text()**. So

change

```
$("#par").text('I\n CANT<br />INSERT<br>LINE BREAKS!'+'<br />'+'FFFF;br/KKK');
```

to

```
$("#par").html('I\n CANT<br />INSERT<br>LINE BREAKS!'+'<br />'+'FFFF;br/KKK');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use html() method instead of text() method.